# Joomla Template Design

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

Can I create any design I want and then use it in a Joomla template or is there certain rules you have to stick to?  I ask this as most of the Joomla templates I see pretty much have the same layout e.g. top bar content box, right hand menu and bottom bar.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla is fairly flexible to build on since its generally a single main html file, its fairly easy to lay it out as you want.

The coomponent (content bit) starts out fairly rigid ut with css you can edit this.

The bigest problem i have found is getting all the css sorted. The design and basic coding can be done fairly quickly but you need to take the time styling afterwards and that’s probably why the templates you have seen have had the head main content footer type of model.

best of luck with the template build

Answer (score 1):

You can almost create any design you want to and create a joomla template. The only problem is if you create it for a customer, it can be very tricky to make it really customizable without confusing the customer.

The most important rule i can say is to find the right modules/components for your need and if not, create your own.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely Joomla has unlimited features for design but must care about Joomla developing rules to get no more errors. You can design and input any flexible design to [Joomla Templates](https://www.themexpert.com/joomla-templates) and Joomla Content Management System. Here we have available link source to get information about Joomla templates.

Thanks